# How to migrate old code from Spring Security 2.0 to 3.0 when it's based on ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, migration

I am sitting here on an old Java code which uses Spring Security 2.0, which have to be migrated to Spring Security 3.0 and up.

My problem now is that there is a class that extends `ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl` which has been removed by refactoring in Spring Security 3.0. The point is I can not find any documentation about this refactoring, and also nothing about the `ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl` class in the Spring Security 2.0 documentation.

The class overwrites the following methods:

```
public void checkAuthenticationAllowed(final Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException;

public void registerSuccessfulAuthentication(final Authentication authentication);
```

Is there a way for migration, or do I have to rewrite the whole applications security layer?

Comment: *and also nothing about the ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl class in the Spring Security 2.0 documentation.* Really? Google's first link for *ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl * is https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/concurrent/ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl.html

Comment: Sorry, when talking about documentation I mean this kind of documentation: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/2.0.x/reference/html/springsecurity.html  So to me the class looks like an Spring internal one that should not be touched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the refactoring of Spring Security the `ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl` has been refactored most partly to `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`.

Where `registerSuccessfulAuthentication` best maps to

```
onAuthentication(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

While `checkAuthenticationAllowed` is now a private method within `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` which can partly be customized via:

```
protected void allowableSessionsExceeded(List<SessionInformation> sessions, int allowableSessions, SessionRegistry registry);

protected int getMaximumSessionsForThisUser(Authentication authentication);
```

Also there are some setters to configure:

```
public void setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(boolean exceptionIfMaximumExceeded);
public void setMaximumSessions(int maximumSessions);
```

For more about `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` have a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/index.html).